# What is the difference between java.rmi.Naming and java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry

Tags: java, rmi, naming

when studying RMI sometimes (head first Java) dudes use

```
Naming.rebind(name, object)
```

but other peoples on the web (oracle) use

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
registry.rebind(name, object);
```

I know that hf java is a little old, but i don't see the Naming class deprecated.

So, what's the difference then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [What's the] difference between `java.rmi.Naming` and `java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry`

The difference is that the `name` field to `Naming.rebind()` is [parsed as an URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/Naming.html#rebind%28java.lang.String,%20java.rmi.Remote%29) while the `Registry.rebind()` is the ["name to associate with the remote reference"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/Registry.html#rebind%28java.lang.String,%20java.rmi.Remote%29).  The `LocateRegistry.getRegistry()` call assumes the registry is on the local host at the default port while the `Naming.rebind()` allows you to specify what registry to use.

Under Java 1.6 `Naming.rebind()` parses the `name` as an URL and calls `Naming.getRegistry()` with the host/port of the registry.  That calls `LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, port)`.

```
public static void rebind(String name, Remote obj) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException 
    ParsedNamingURL parsed = parseURL(name);
    Registry registry = getRegistry(parsed);
    if (obj == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("cannot bind to null");
    registry.rebind(parsed.name, obj);
}
...

private static Registry getRegistry(ParsedNamingURL parsed) throws RemoteException {
    return LocateRegistry.getRegistry(parsed.host, parsed.port);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

No difference if you look at the source code then you will see this :

```
public static void rebind(String name, Remote obj)
throws RemoteException, java.net.MalformedURLException {
    ParsedNamingURL parsed = parseURL(name);
    Registry registry = getRegistry(parsed);

    if (obj == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("cannot bind to null");

    registry.rebind(parsed.name, obj);
}
```

Disclaimer : Code taken from JDK not my own impl.

Similar question [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/180244/java-developer-SCJD/certification/Registry-rebind-or-Naming-rebind)